# Couldn't match type ‘Either SomeCardanoApiTx Tx’ with ‘Tx’

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I have this error when compiling Week01 from Pioneer Program:

```
error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Either SomeCardanoApiTx Tx’ with ‘Tx’
  Expected type: Tx
    Actual type: CardanoTx
• In the first argument of ‘txId’, namely ‘ledgerTx’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘txId ledgerTx’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx’

void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have built Plutus from the latest commit, some things have changed I believe. The reason is `submitTxConstraintsWith` returns a type of `Contract w s e CardanoTx` but `txId` requires the type `Tx`. Replace `TxId` with `getCardanoTxId` and it should work.

If you want to follow the Pioneer Program tutorials you need to build with the commit hash used in the lectures, for lesson 1 it is: `ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4`

Comment: But I want to use a recent version.

Comment: the `getCardanoTxId` fixed for me, thx!